# MySQL row headers based off order by field grouping in query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I would like to output row grouping headers in a MySQL query based off of the ORDER BY field.  Not sure how to explain this so it is best to just shown an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
SELECT * FROM products_table
ORDER BY Category, Description


Prod_num Category Description Price
type_1
00001    type_1   Prod 1      $1
00002    type_1   Prod 2      $2
00003    type_1   Prod 3      $3
00004    type_1   Prod 4      $4
00005    type_1   Prod 5      $5
type_2
00006    type_2   Prod 6      $6
00007    type_2   Prod 7      $7
00008    type_2   Prod 8      $8
00009    type_2   Prod 9      $9
type_3
00010    type_3   Prod 10     $10
00011    type_3   Prod 11     $11
```

I would like the category field to be shown as a row header before displaying all products with that category. I think I have seen this posted somewhere but after a lot of searching have not been able to figure out how to do it mainly because I think I am not using the proper terminology.

Answer (score 3):

I am a firm believer that this should be done on the presentation side of your code, however, this is how I've seen it done in the past using `GROUP BY` and `WITH ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT  Category, 
        IFNULL(prod_num,'') Prod_Num, 
        IFNULL(description,'') Description, 
        IFNULL(price,'') Price
FROM    
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM   Products_Table
    GROUP BY Category,Prod_num,Description,Price
    WITH ROLLUP
  ) AS X
WHERE Category IS NOT NULL
  AND (
    (Prod_num IS NOT NULL AND Description IS NOT NULL AND Price IS NOT NULL)
     OR 
    (Prod_num IS NULL AND Description IS NULL AND Price IS NULL)
  )
ORDER BY Category,Prod_num,Description,Price
```

This isn't 100% what you asked for because it puts the Category column first -- I haven't played with it enough to see if that can be altered.

Here are the results:

```
CATEGORY  PROD_NUM  DESCRIPTION  PRICE
type_1          
type_1    00001     Prod 1       $1
type_1    00002     Prod 2       $2
type_2          
type_2    00003     Prod 3       $3
type_2    00004     Prod 4       $4
type_2    00005     Prod 5       $5
type_3          
type_3    00006     Prod 6       $6
```

And a sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68ef9/1).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html